# Using distinct in Neo4j queries

Tags: neo4j

I'm learning Neo4j and I see that some Match clause can retrieve multiple times the same node, so you need to specify DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates being nodes or aggregated values as for

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d:Person)
collect(DISTINCT m.title) as movies
RETURN p.name as Actor, movies AS Movies, d.name AS Director
```

I'm wondering in what cases would one want to keep duplicates.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not any specific cases, in which you want duplicates. It basically depends on the functionality you are trying to achieve.

Consider this scenario: We want all the movie titles to which a person is linked somehow directly. In this case, you'll probably use `DISTINCT`, because a `Person` can be linked both as an `Actor` and `Director` to a movie. The query will be:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[]->(m)
WITH p, collect(DISTINCT m.title) as movies
RETURN p.name as Actor, movies AS Movies
```

In another scenario, you just want the movies a person is linked to as an actor. In this case, there is no need to use `DISTINCT`, because a person will be linked to a movie as an Actor, ideally only once. So this would suffice:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WITH p, collect(m.title) as movies
RETURN p.name as Actor, movies AS Movies
```

Mostly aggregation operations are the places, where we use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates, in counts, lists, etc. You can also use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows from the output if there are any, but again it's functionality dependent, there are no hard and fast rules as such. If the query you are trying returns duplicates, and you don't want them, use `DISTINCT`, otherwise, let it be as it is.

Comment: Sure I see that in cases where you are sure that the result won't produce any duplicates you can safely avoid using DISTINCT as in yous second example. But wouldn't it be safe to use it as default so you will never get duplicates for sure? I'm sure that this would impact performances negatively so it's better to use it only when needed..

Comment: You can set it as default. But there are two problems with that. One of course the efficiency. I have seen queries that applied distinct while collecting large JSON objects, for which they took 11M db hits, so poor efficiency. Another pain point is, it can hide certain data-inconsistencies which shouldn't be there in the first place. As an example, in the second query, if we use distinct by default, we will not get duplicates, but if there exists two acted relations b/w a person and movie, than that's the inconsistency we need to find and fix, otherwise in the longer run it will be a problem.

Comment: Oh sure, I see. So I'd imagine that for discovering data-inconsistencies in the second example yo'd have in place ( in testing ) a query without DISTINCT and another one with, so you can compare number of results.. or how do you set things up?

Comment: Yeah, you can set up a test case to compare the outputs of two queries (with and without distinct) and make it fail, if it doesn't match.

Comment: sweet..got it. thank you very match for your help and time